# Style ng-bootstrap accordion with css

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an Angular 2 component with an accordion, which I added using ng-bootstrap. Everything works fine functionally, however the styles that I try to load using the `.card, .card-header, .card-block` classes that the compiled accordion elements have, those styles do not get applied to the elements at all.

These classes are set by ng-bootstrap directly, when transforming the accordion into div's.

I apply my own css via a styles.scss file that I link to the components TypeScript file. When everything is rendered, my styles appear in the `<style></style>` tags in the header of the html output.
It looks like this.

```
    <style>
        [_nghost-xfh-23]   .card[_ngcontent-xfh-23] {
          border: none; }

    [_nghost-xfh-23]   .card-header[_ngcontent-xfh-23] {
      margin-top: 0.75em !important;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125); }

    [_nghost-xfh-23]   .card-block[_ngcontent-xfh-23] {
      text-align: left; }
    </style>
```

The styles.scss looks like this:

```
:host .card {
  border: none;
}

:host .card-header {
  margin-top: 0.75em !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

:host .card-block {
  text-align: left;

}
```

My guess is that Angular 2 is trying to apply the styles (during compilation), but creates the div's with the said classes afterwards, making it impossible to apply the styles to the elements.

Im restrained to edit the bootstrap.css directly or create an other global css file. I'm hoping there is a way to reapply the css styles after the component is loaded or some other means to style ng-bootstrap accordions.

Hope my problem makes sense,
regards
Sy

Comment: What is the css of these class? How do you add those classes? How do you implement the styles ? We need a bit more information to help you.

Comment: @DomeTune made it a bit more detailed, hope that helps.

Comment: This sounds like you've encountered the shadow DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM 

If you add `:deep:` or `>>>` to your css rules

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @ChristopherMoore said in his comment, it was a problem due to Shadow DOM. Adding `/deep/` fixed it. Here the updated functional code.

```
  /deep/ .card {
  border: none;
}

/deep/ .card-header {
  margin-top: 0.75em !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

/deep/ .card-block {
  text-align: left
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue but I want to change the styles of some cards and not all since I am using nested accordion and want different styles for the card.

I have applied a `.inner-accordion` class to the accordion and want to modify the styles of `.card` class which is inside the `inner-accordion` class. Any inputs on how to implement this?

Comment: Got it working. It would work like below:
`.inner-accordion ::ng-deep .card`